# Symfony2 forms confirm password without repeated field type

Tags: forms, symfony

Registration forms usually feature a confirmation field for passwords. We can achieve this in Symfony2 by using a [repeated](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) field type.

However, say that you are building you're registration form as follows:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('user', new UserType());
        $builder->add(
            'terms',
            'checkbox',
            array('property_path' => 'termsAccepted')
        );
        $builder->add('Register', 'submit');
    }
...
```

FWIW, this is actually taken from a [Symfony tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html).

The problem here is that we add a UserType that already contains a password field.

One solution is to use a [repeated](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) field type in UserType. However, I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this without modifying UserType?

I thought about adding a field in the Registration class:

```
/**
 * @Assert\EqualTo($this->user.getPassword())
 */
protected $confirmPassword;
```

but the getPassword() method actually returns the hashed password so I am unsure whether I am on the right track with this..

How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood completely, but I'll give it a shot.

The fact that `getPassword()` returns hash value only tells you that you need to go in reverse: hash the plain text value and then compare it. But that is a bit weird/invalid to do within the entity, since you do not have access to container nor to any service.

I suggest the following approach:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // the rest of your registration form, what you already have

        $encoderFactory = $options['encoder_factory'];

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($encoderFactory) {
            // Instance of Registration
            $data = $event->getData();

            $encoder = $encoderFactory->getEncoder($data->getUser());

            // Second argument should be the salt or null. Do you intend to use it?
            $hash = $encoder->encodePassword($data->getConfirmPassword(), .... ); 

            // Overwrite the palin text value with hash
            $data->setConfirmPassword($hash);
        });
    }
```

### The key points:

1. You will need to pass an `encoder_factory` to your registration form.
2. Later, after the `setConfirmPassword()` call has completed, validation will run and **run positive if passwords match**.

So, is this what you were trying to do, at all? :)

P.S. Pardon the potential errors, I am typing this right out of my head into the Notepad++...

Comment: Did not try it but I see your point. I guess this would make my code unnecessarily complicated. I will go for updating my UserType class instead. Seems more adequate.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar issue by applying the comparison with property plainPassword for those using FOS_user.
Taken from a [Symfony tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/EqualTo.html).

```
<code>
 /**
  * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath="plainPassword")
  */
 protected $confirmPassword;
</code>
```